# PFSense with client certificates, SSL cert hosting

Tags: firewall, pfsense

I'm running a PFSense firewall that is doing load balancing to a number of IIS servers.  I'd like to host the SSL Certificate on the pfsense firewall instead of the individual IIS servers.  I'd also like to be able to restrict clients that can connect to the https server on a certain public IP address to a list of client certificates (managed by pfsense).  Looking at the web gui, it appears to only allow rules certificate rules if the client is connected to the VPN.

Is this possible?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

PFSense is a modular firewall distribution based on Freebsd.  It can be extended via either Apache, Mod_security, Squid, or Openvpn (and others).

I'd use:

- Apache for HTTP serving and extensibility
- Mod_security for web application protections
- Squid for proxy functionality / reverse proxy / caching
- Openvpn for VPN functionality

As you can access the x509 certificate functionality in above products, yes, it is possible.  You can read over some of the x509 client TLS vpn information at

http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/VPN_Capability_OpenVPN

There is also a way to use Squid to do traffic interception, called SSLbump

http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/SslBump

I'd recommend using an offline CA for some of the PKI specific ideas, and evaluating the PFsense compatibility list with crypto offload devices (HSMs).

There are ethical considerations in traffic interception that are greater for external clients than are for internal employees.  Employees can easily be addressed via a standard - we can read everything, intercept everything, etc type of EULA click through, such as the one that DoD uses, e.g. https://dod411.gds.disa.mil/

Because I am lazy and security paranoid, I'd prefer to do something a little different than what you mentioned: multiple tunnels & Out of Band Management

**Multiple tunnels**

client ---- Network device <<<<<< Tunnel 1, IPSEC >>>>>>> PFSense ---- IIS

client -------- Tunnel 2, IPSEC -------- IIS

Keep in mind that IPSEC is more complex than TLS, with better security, at a cost of usability.  You can also use TLS and IPSEC vpn types together.

**Out of Band management**

Create another network specific to management, and isolate it from production (data) traffic.  Enable incoming management only via the management interface.  Disable all but production traffic on the production side.  Make your rules rigid, via a gradual tightening process.  Enforce least privilege on your IIS servers with the bare minimum (HTTP or HTTPS) talking on the production network side.

While this is more work than what you asked in the question

- You can rest easier knowing your security is tighter
- Your auditors are likely to love you :)